# How can I divide distance between different years into 12 equal section in python

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a plot. This plot shows data for four years.

[image]

I want to show months between different years on the x-axis. I don't want to show the name of months. I just want to divide the space between different years into 12 sections. This is my code.

```
data['Date']=pd.to_datetime(data['Date'])
date = data['Date']
Delta_x = data['as']
Delta_y = data['ad']
Delta = data['af']
amount = data['final']
cc = data['cc']
sc=plt.scatter(date,amount, c=cc, cmap=plt.cm.RdGy)
cbar = plt.colorbar(sc, orientation='vertical', shrink=0.5)
plt.ylabel('Seismic Velocity Change (%)')
plt.ylim(-0.35, 0.25)
plt.axhline(y=0, color='gray', linestyle='--')
plt.axvspan(date2num(datetime(2017,11,7)), date2num(datetime(2017,11,30)), alpha=0.6, color='lightsteelblue')
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dividing into 12 minor ticks can be achieved by:

```
ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator(12))
```

A MWE:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import AutoMinorLocator

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10,4))

ax = fig.add_subplot()

x = [2000,2001,2002,2003]
y = [2000,2001,2002,2003]

ax.xaxis.set_minor_locator(AutoMinorLocator(12))

ax.plot(x,y)

plt.show()
```

[image]